# R HTML clean up - how to get rid of strange characters in output?

Tags: html, r, unicode, html-parsing, character

I'm using R to clean up html files stored in my hard drive and then export as txt files. However, in the output text files I see a lot of strange characters such as < U+0093>,< U+0094> < U+0093> etc. It seems to me either quote mark or bullet point (or maybe some others) is not parsed/displayed correctly. How do I fix this issue?

Here is the [original HTML file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ba8au7cgtxv1gpe/2488-R20130221-C20121229-F22-0-1.htm?dl=0)

Below is the code I've been using:

```
library(bitops)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
rawHTML <- paste(readLines("2488-R20130221-C20121229-F22-0-1.htm"), collapse="\n") 
doc = htmlParse(rawHTML, asText=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)][not(ancestor::form)]", xmlValue)
write.table(plain.text, file="2488.txt", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the text, you an do a conversion to ASCII with `iconv`. Also, you don't need to use `write.table` for this as `writeLines` will do nicely:

```
library(bitops)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

rawHTML <- paste(readLines("~/Dropbox/2488-R20130221-C20121229-F22-0-1.htm"), collapse="\n") 
doc <- htmlParse(rawHTML, asText=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)][not(ancestor::form)]", xmlValue)
writeLines(iconv(plain.text, to="ASCII"), "~/Dropbox/2488wl.txt")
```

You could also use `rvest` (you still need `iconv`):

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

pg <- html("~/Dropbox/2488-R20130221-C20121229-F22-0-1.htm")

target <- "//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)][not(ancestor::form)]"

pg %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath=target) %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  iconv(to="ASCII") %>% 
  writeLines("~/Dropbox/2488rv.txt")
```

You can also avoid pipes if you want to:

```
converted <- iconv(html_text(html_nodes(pg, xpath=target)), to="ASCII")
writeLines(converted, "~/Dropbox/2488rv.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried 'to="ASCII"' but lots of content are lost, instead, only a few "NA"s are shown. Once I changed that to UTF-8 it turned out to be just fine. Do you know what cause this?

Comment: Also, sometimes there're quite a lot of white spaces between lines, do you happen to know how to get rid of them (i.e., make the output tighter)?

Comment: Glad UTF-8 worked (didn't know exactly what you needed though I'm surprised UTF-8 did work). ASCII is most compatible, but far more restrictive. I'll update post for the lines thing.

Comment: Thanks, I've about 30K html files to clean, hopefully UTF-8 would work. Now I know that ASCII is the most compatible, what other encoding would you recommend?

Comment: Although not perfect, below is how I trim some whitespaces: `write.table(iconv(str_trim(plain.text,"both"), to="UTF-8"), file="test.txt",row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)`

Comment: A follow up question has been posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900980/r-html-clean-up-done-but-how-to-remove-white-spaces-connect-words-together)

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to use for-loop to generate txt output, but got stuck, could you take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657701/use-r-for-loop-to-clean-html-files-and-then-generate-txt-outputs) and help me out?